# Does the convergence of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n$ imply the convergence of the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x_n $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

True or False:
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  x_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x_n $ is convergent.

Comment: Try $x_n=(-1)^n\frac 1n$

Comment: Thanks hagen for the counterexample :)

Answer (score 2):

With the additional hypothesis that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, your claim holds. It is called the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

We can actually use this to prove that it does not hold in the general case. Take $$x_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$$ whose series converges and see that

$$(-1)^n (-1)^n x_n = (-1)^{2n} \frac1n = \frac 1n$$
whose series does not converge.