# If $a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can think of some special cases. For example, if $a_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n$, then:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^na_{n}| =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^n||a_{n}| =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1.|a_{n}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}  $$

So the alternating series converges.

Similarly, if all $a_{n} < 0$, then:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^na_{n}| = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}  $$

Which again converges.

But the problem simply asks to prove or disprove it for *any* $a_{n}$, so I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653901/does-the-convergence-of-a-series-sum-n-1-infty-x-n-imply-the-convergence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\sum(-1)^n{1\over n}$ converges but not $\sum(-1)^n(-1)^n{1\over n}$